# Hibernate set null has no saved,then data has been deleted

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

Entity:(Some attributes are omitted)

Storage:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_storage")
public class Storage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8067092629525887737L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade= CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinTable(name = "t_purchase_storage", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "storage_id") },inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "purchase_id") })
    private List<Purchase> purchases = Lists.newArrayList();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "auth_user_storage", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "storage_id")}, inverseJoinColumns =
            {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "auth_user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2577286098148701829L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "auth_user_storage", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns =
            {@JoinColumn(name = "storage_id")})
    private Set<Storage> storages = Sets.newHashSet();

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
}
```

**Step**:
1.want to select some storages

```
        List<Storage> storageList = storageService.findAllStorage(null);
        storageList.forEach(store -> {
            store.setPurchases(null);
            store.setCheckUsers(null);
            store.setUsers(null);
            store.setStorageBins(null);
        });
        return ResponseEntity.ok(JsonResult.success(storageList));
```

2.AopLog called UserServiceImpl a method

```
 controllerLog.setOperatorName(userService.findUserNameById(id));
```

this serviceImpl has @Transaction

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Override
    public String findUserNameById(Long userId) {
        return userRepository.findUsernameById(userId);
    }

}
```

3. 

When executing userRepository.findUsernameById, then the previous property of setnull was deleted

log:

```
2021-03-29 17:04:06.991 [http-nio-7779-exec-1] INFO  com.~~.api.web.log.AopLog - 【返回值】：<200 OK,class   JsonResult {
    code: 001
    msg: ok
    data: [com.~~.entity.Storage@21]
},{}>

Hibernate: delete from t_checkuser_storage where storage_id=?  
Hibernate: delete from t_purchase_storage where storage_id=?  
Hibernate: delete from auth_user_storage where storage_id=?  
Hibernate: select username from auth_user where id=?
```

**solve**
Remove transaction annotation on the serviceImpl, then has no problem.

or not set null, return VO.

**problem**
I didn't do any save or delete operations. Why are the properties that are left blank deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `@Transactional`, the entity returned by the query is managed for the duration of the transaction. It means that at commit time, any changes applied to the entity is going to be propagated to the database. So, setting to null those values is equivalent to an update query on the db.

When you remove `@Transactional`, the entity stops being managed as soon as it's returned by the query. For this reason, changes won't be propagated to the database.

Comment: On the surface, I didn't do any save operations. Should I try not to add transaction annotations to any query operations? In order to avoid this kind of query update

Comment: It depends from what your app is doing with the retrieved data. Maybe in this particular case you don't need the transaction but you might need it somewhere else. The point is that with Hibernate ORM, updating a managed object is the same as making an update query. You don't have to call a save method explicitly. Also, why don't you only return the value that you need from the query? It seems better than setting values to null on the bin each time.

Comment: Because the lazy loading I set doesn't seem to work in JPA queries~

Comment: There could  be several reasons for that. For open questions about HIbernate ORM, the Zulip chat might be a better place: https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/login/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user